# How do i view all transactions in JMeter Report

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am running performance test using JMeter 5.0 and then at the end of the test a HTML report is generated. I would like to know if there is anyway to view actual request with the endpoint it served what was the response and ability to view all requests in HTML report. I know JMeter has something called view result tree and it provides most of the information i need but i am not sure how to display result tree or something similar in HTML report.

Answer (score 1):

View results is tree is rather resource intensive listener so you want to use it with caution. Typically you want to filter and display only errors so you can analyse them.

[image: Results Tree Filter Errors]

If you would like HTML reports then you can use a modular extension for JMeter.  Its default behavior is to read and process samples from CSV files to generate HTML files containing graph views. It can generate the report at end of a load test or on demand.

You can generate the HTML report using menu item Tools → Generate HTML report:

[image: Generate HTML Reports]

[This page](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) explains different configs and options to tweak and tune the report generation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Filtering by errors in the results tree is something I would have really benefitted from in my last test!! Didn't even think to look at that option!!

Answer (score 1):

As of current [JMeter version 5.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter-5.2/)

1. JMeter can [only generate the HTML Reporting Dashboard from the CSV files](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#overview)

   > The dashboard generator is a modular extension of JMeter. Its default behavior is to read and process samples **from CSV files** to generate HTML files containing graph views. It can generate the report at end of a load test or on demand.
2. There is no [possibility to store response data in CSV mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config):

   > `response_data` is currently **not supported** for CSV output

So there is no easy way to implement your issue unless you use i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) to store request/response data into a separate file and modify [report-template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.2/bin/report-template) (you will need to learn [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/)) to display the information you need.

Comment: @Dimitri - Is it likely that writing out the request/response data with the Flexible File Write cause significant overhead on test response times?

Answer (score 0):

use this command,  -g .jtl file -o reportlocationpath, you will get nicely generated html report along lots of graphs as shown below:
[image]

Comment: thank you for the info but i already have a HTML report generated, I have one HTTP request that iterates through thousands of CSV rows. what i want is that i want to see if i can have something equivalent to result tree in HTML report

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if there is anyway to view actual request with
>   the endpoint it served

My guess is that you already have all the metrics required for each request but would like to see individual request payload and the response. Just in case this guess is wrong, since you already have the report and are still not able to see the individual requests, I am assuming that you have checked on "Generate Parent Sample" across each Transaction Controller. Uncheck that and you should be able to see individual request level response time, 90th percentile etc. Of course you will have to re-run the test to get these individual request level values

However, if you want to literally see the request payload and response in HTML report, there is no way we can do that. Only View Results Tree can do that for you within the scope of JMeter's GUI and not outside of this.

> what was the response

As mentioned above, as of today, there is no possibility to see the response of individual requests along with their payload in the HTML report and this is for a good reason. We do not require the requests/responses while we run a load test in our HTML report. It is necessary for debugging and until the script is ready for execution. But post that, we wouldn't require the responses. If you still want to ensure that the correct responses are received, you can always add [assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) (although best practice is not to add too many assertions in a load test)

Just an example of why HTML report across any load testing tool will not show responses of a request -

Assume there is a load test of 10K users for 10 iterations and the Thread Group has around 10 transactions each having an average of 7 requests, there is going to be 7 million responses to go through. Having this in a HTML report is not just tedious but literally doesn't make sense.

> I know JMeter has something called view result tree and it provides
>   most of the information i need

The View Results Tree is the holy grail for debugging and for ensuring if requests and response are appropriate during script creation stage.

I think your primary concern is to ensure the correctness of the responses rather than get the whole response of each request. In that case, as I had mentioned above, you can always use assertions. Several other custom alternatives include capturing specific parts of response and writing them to a file or something like that by leveraging JSR223 sampler or using the if controller to validate. Of course this is going to add some overhead on JMeter depending on the type of test and script that you are going to execute

> but i am not sure how to display result tree or something similar in
>   HTML report

But if you still insist on having something in HTML and if I have failed to convince as to why this is something that one must not pursue, you can capture the entire response of each request in a variable through Regex Extractor and write them to a file with HTML tags in it. However, you will have to implement logic to collate responses and organize them for your need.

One more way would be to have the JTL save all data and modify this up in some text editor and beautify it with HTML

FYI on JTL and its configuration
[image]

Hope this helps!